# Glue: What is the right type for an array of int in a Glue script?

Tags: arrays, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I want to map the content of an S3 bucket to a dynamic frame, and in particular the field "fasi" which is an array of integers.

The destination table has the following schema, which was created providing `ARRAY <INT>`  as the array schema:

```
{
  "fasi": "int[]"
}
```

The generated script had this block:

```py
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=S3bucket_node1,
    mappings=[
        ...
        ("fasi", "int array", "fasi", "int array"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)
```

which gives an error: `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name int array`.

Restarting from scratch, the new code was generated as ("fasi", "array", "fasi", "array"), which gives no error. However, when accessing the data through Athena (following Glue's redirect), I get the following error `GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: type expected at the position 0 of 'array <int>' but 'array ' is found.` .

What is the correct way of mapping an array of integers?

As a summary, I tried the following combinations, which all give errors.

| attempt | error |
| --- | --- |
| `("fasi", "int array", "fasi", "int_array")` | `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name int array` |
| `("fasi", "int_array", "fasi", "int array")` | `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name int_array` |
| `("fasi", "array", "fasi", "array <int>")` | `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name array <int>` |
| `("fasi", "[int]", "fasi", "[int]")` | `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type name [int]` |
| `("fasi", ArrayType(IntegerType()), "fasi", ArrayType(IntegerType()))` (imported from `pyspark.sql.types`) | `AttributeError: 'ArrayType' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'` |